# How to import pymaps in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pygmaps

I want to plot my gps data on google maps using python. I searched & found that pygmaps does the thing but I'm getting error when I import this file it says "'module' object has no attribute 'maps'". I've saved this file in libs folder in python27 in c drive. What should i do now ?

```
import pygmaps
mymap = pygmaps.maps(18.458184, 73.850781, 14)
mymap.addpoint(18.458184, 73.850781, '#0000FF')
mymap.draw('./mymap.html')
```

Comment: Can you write the error

Comment: Please share the code you've tried and the error you're getting

Comment: Please also report the link of the pygmaps you are using. The error means that `map` does not exist in `pygmaps`. You can check what a package offers by typing on the console `help(pygmaps)`, after importing it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code should be like the following:

```
import pygmaps
mymap = pygmaps.pygmaps(18.458184, 73.850781, 14)
mymap.addpoint(18.458184, 73.850781, '#0000FF')
mymap.draw('./mymap.html')
```